# Forward / remap multiple topics to a single topic?

Tags: ros, multiple, remap, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there already a way to forward / aggregate multiple topics to a single topic?

I tried remapping with `rostopic echo`, but found that the last remapping argument takes precedence.
Example in bash:

```
# Spin up unique publishers
rostopic pub -r 5 /test/a std_msgs/Float64 "data: 0.0" &
rostopic pub -r 5 /test/b std_msgs/Float64 "data: 20.0" &

# Echo with remapping
rostopic echo /test/c /test/c:=/test/a /test/c:=/test/b
```

The output shows '20.0', meaning b's data is the only one getting through.

For the time being, I wrote a script to aggregate the topics: [topic_aggregator.py](https://gist.github.com/eacousineau/6986950)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90901/forward-/-remap-multiple-topics-to-a-single-topic?/) by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will [topic_tools/relay](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/relay) do what you want?

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on 2013-10-15**:
Seems like it only handles a single topic. I tried out `topic_tools/mux`, which handles multiple topics, but running `rostopic echo` only showed '0.0'. Will look a little more into it.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-15**:
mux switches between topics, it doesn't merge them.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-10-15**:
If I understand your question correctly, two instances of relay should do what you want, one that does /test/a -> /test/c and one that does /test/b -> /test/c

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on 2013-10-16**:
Ah, that works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My intuition says no, because that will be two distinct connections.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-10-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on 2013-10-15**:
That makes sense.